Fourier series of a block Toeplitz matrices
Herglotz's Theorem states that if $(a_{n})_{n \in \mathbf{Z}}$ be a positive definite sequence and suppose $a_0=1$. Then there exists a probability measure $\mu$ on $[-\pi, \pi]$ such that  $a_n= \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{-inx} d\mu (x)$.
Here $(a_{n})_{n \in \mathbf{Z}}$ is a sequence of real number. Instead of real number, consider the $k\times k$ complex matrix-valued Fourier transformation $f: (-\pi,\pi)\rightarrow \mathbb{M}_k$ with Fourier coefficient  $A_n= \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{-inx} f(x) dx$. I noticed this matrix version of Herglotz's Theorem, stated in Miranda and Tilli's in terms of block Toeplitz Matrix. However, I could not locate the complete construction of its proof, the positivity of the corresponding block Toeplitz matrices at various levels (the Toeplitz matrices have to be Hermitian as we consider it on $\mathbb{C}$), and the convergence of the Fourier series. Kindly help.

Where do you encountered this question? What relevant courses you took?

Basic function analysis and Operator theory.   Some knowledge in matrix theory
